# Google Contacts API with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-shared-contacts, google-profiles-api

I have a CodeIgniter application and I want access Google Contact API with OAuth solution. I want changes to be made in the Google Contact API when they are made in the database.

Already there is a Google account, have a client ID and client secret.

Please tell me what further steps should I take with Google Contacts and Google Developers Console.

Also, please tell me what files I need to add in Codeigniter and where to place them and the code I need to put in them.

I am new to Google API, CodeIgniter, PHP and web.

Comment: Welcome to stack, we would be happy to help you fix problems with your code but we cant do it for you.  start here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/ come back with any problems you have.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you - DalmTo - but it does not contain any php - what can I do - thank you

Comment: Second place to start: https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client

Comment: [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto) - I have been working on this from a long time and I didn't have much progress - it is really important for me to do this. Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: [DalmTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1841839/daimto)  - I have just been able to create a new page all by itself which can access the google contacts, import them and display. - However, I want my codeigniter application to access google contacts and make changes in the google contacts when they are made in the database - Thanks a lot

Comment: WebSuccess: to notify people here, use @DaImTo, not a hyperlink of their user profile. I don't need to do the same however, since you automatically get notifications on your posts.